# Singular Value Decomposition algorithm

Tags: svd

I am trying to use Singular Value Decomposition algorithm from numpy library (numpy-MKL-1.6.2.win-amd64-py2.7), but I propose that this function doesn't correct. This function has the following statement:

```
from numpy.linalg import *

U, S, V = svd(A, full_matrices=0)
```

My assumption is based on comparison comparison with the same function in Matlab, which gives a correct answer. I also found that the problems related to the wrong calculation of V matrix.

For example, I have matrix A:

```
A =[-15.5714,   19.2143,   15.0000; -2.8462,    7.7692,   -3.9615; -19.5000,   3.1111,    4.5556]
```

In python I receive:

```
V = [0.7053,  -0.5629,   -0.4308; -0.6863,   -0.6945,   -0.2161; -0.1776,    0.4481,   -0.8762]
```

and in Matlab:

```
V = [0.7053,   -0.6863,   -0.1776; -0.5629,   -0.6945,    0.4481; -0.4308,   -0.2161,   -0.8762]
```

Differences are not so evident, but they become critical during LLS calculations.
How can I overcome this problem?

OK, I found the answer:
   [U,S,V]=svd(a) - Matlab
   U, S, Vh = linalg.svd(a), V = Vh.T - Python
Maybe my question helps someone in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Matlab `V` matrix and numpy `V` matrix are transposes of each other.

You can use the [transpose()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) function to obtain the transposed version.

Answer (score 1):

The domain matrices **U** and **V** in the singular value decomposition are not unique, so it is difficult to compare results from different math engines. (The matrix of singular values is unique. Unfortunately it is not posted.)

A quick quality check is to look at the column vectors of the domain matrices. As these matrices are unitary each column vector has unit length in the 2 norm. For the python result these norms are (0.999947, 1.00002, 1.00003); for MATLAB we have a superior result (0.999999, 0.99999, 1.00001). Mathematica surpasses this with (1.0000000000000002, 1.0000000000000004, 1.0000000000000000).

• Addendum:
The SVD aligns the vectors spaces of the domain and codomain. There may be only one alignment. There may be a discrete set of alignment angles. There may be a continuous set of angles as shown here:

[image]